# Too many threads created when pausing application that uses IOCP

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

So, I have built a heavily multi-threaded and concurrent application which manages its own worker threads (as they run for the entire application life time). Now I use SocketAsyncEventArgs for networking, which uses I/O Completion ports behind the scenes.

When I run the app normally, it's all fine, I get about ~30-60 threads (including my own worker threads) in the app.

But when I *pause* the app in visual studio while debugging, the mount of threads will easily rise up to a couple of hundred (worst case so far was 500+). Now I realize (?) that this comes from pausing the application and the new threads spawning for the I/O ports, but is there a way to stop this from happening as the amount of threads make visual studio halt for ~20 seconds and makes it very hard to debug.

Comment: Stop sending data before you pause?

Comment: There is some 'break across all threads' option IIRC.

Comment: Would it make more sense to just break individual threads you are interested in instead of "break all" on the whole application?  
Also, I find debug logging (ie: printf/Debugger.Log) easier to use in multi-threaded environments...

Answer (score 0):

This is why there are generally thread limits on thread pools. Sounds like what's going on is each network event is firing up a new thread. This can be expensive, certainly more expensive than recycling threads. I think the way this is generally done is you have a single thread picking off the network and placing things into a buffer. When the buffer is full you stop picking things up off the network (or drop the info). There is a different set of threads that are picking things off the buffer and processing them.

What sounds like is happening in your application is that each incoming network request spawns a new thread. The thread that listens for these new threads is blocked by the debugger or perhaps these new threads are blocked by the debugger as well. Either way, new threads keep getting spawned and blocked by the debugger. I'm not really sure how you would even set this up except perhaps if you had a receive function that looked like:

```
public void Recv(object sender, EventArguments ea)
{
     Thread.Start(new ThreadMain());
     // do some more stuff <-- this is where you block
}
```

You should not need to start a new thread from your async receive method.

Comment: I can assure you this is not happening, I do not start any new threads, and the threads that starts are not managed threads, but native ones (IOCP Threads to be specific).

Comment: Well, it was a shot in the dark. Hard to tell much without some sample code. Can you whittle down your code to a small amount that would repro the issue? Perhaps you can see what method all the new threads are starting/stopping at in the debugger?